# What is the meaning of the UV =? IR statement in String theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory

I was looking through these notes http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/six.pdf and on page 146 it says "This corresponds to the fact that any putative
UV divergence of string theory can always be reinterpreted as an IR divergence. This
is the second manifestation of the well-behaved UV nature of string theory" . I am not exactly sure that I understand the background described before it and why this is true. Can anyone care to simplify what they are saying, and also, do they really mean it when they say IR is UV or are they making some deeper claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of integrating over the region in moduli space where $\Im(\tau) \to 0$ (corresponding to the UV limit), we can perform a modular transformation and integrate over the region where $\Im(\tau) \to \infty$ (corresponding to the IR limit).

I think that's all he wants to say, there is (as far as I understand it) nothing deeper behind it. But it is not really clear yet at this point in the notes why those regions correspond to the UV or to the IR. Try reading and understanding the next pages, especially subsection 6.4.3. There, it becomes much more explicit in an example. On page 152, he concludes:

> This highlights our previous statement: the potential UV divergences in field theory
>   are encountered in the region $\Im(\tau) \sim l \to 0$. In the above analysis, this corresponds to
>   particles traversing small loops. But this region is simply absent in the correct string
>   theory computation. It is mapped, by modular invariance, to the infra-red region of
>   large loops.